# Facebook Android SDK 3.0 and Lollipop

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm having a problem with an explicit Intent found in the Facebook SDK on Lollipop. Before Api v21 this only supposedly raised an error but now it throws an exception. I'm wondering if there is a fix to turn this into an implicit intent. The part which fails is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NativeProtocol.INTENT_ACTION_PLATFORM_SERVICE);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent = NativeProtocol.validateKatanaServiceIntent(context, intent);

    if (intent == null) {
        callback(null);
        return false;
    } else {
        running = true;
        context.bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        return true;
    }
```

What I tried is to set the package name like:

```
intent.setPackage("com.facebook");
```

But that didnt work.

Any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way to it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NativeProtocol.INTENT_ACTION_PLATFORM_SERVICE);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent = NativeProtocol.validateKatanaServiceIntent(context, intent);
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(intent, 0);
    if (intent == null) {
        callback(null);
        return false;
    } else {
        running = true;
        intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.serviceInfo.packageName);
        context.bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        return true;
    }
```

If anyone else needed this.